# How to disable [Shift + Enter] shortcut in Opera Browser?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opera

When typing a query into google search I always seem to accidenally push the `Shift+Enter` keys instead of just the `Enter` key. This causes the search results to open in a new browser window instead of the current tab.

How can I disable this `Shift+Enter` key combination?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest might be to use a third-party tool such as [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) and add the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> for an innocuous program such as CMD, or to perform some other task. That should 'steal' the keypress.